# Gradle Spring-data-dynamo db

Tags: java, spring, gradle, amazon-dynamodb

I am using a project where I want to use spring 4.2.5-RELEASE with gradle. I want to use Amazon DynamoDb with it. My problem is I add the dependency code in gradle but I am unable to find the following classes:

- @EnableDynamoDBRepositories
- AmazonDynamoDB
- AmazonDynamoDBClient
- AWSCredentials
- BasicAWSCredentials

I am not sure what I am missing. My build.gradle has

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile ("com.github.derjust:spring-data-dynamodb:4.2.0")
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get a local instance of DynamoDB running:  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-local-for-desktop-development/

Add the following Repo to your *build.gradle*

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.opensourceagility.com/release/" }
}
```

Add these dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '1.10.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-dynamodb', version: '1.11.34'
    compile group: 'org.socialsignin', name: 'spring-data-dynamodb', version: '4.2.1'
}
```

Add these Properties:

```
amazon.dynamodb.endpoint=http://localhost:8000/
amazon.aws.accesskey=key
amazon.aws.secretkey=key2
```

Create a data model:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Table")
public class Table {
    private String id;

    public Table() {}

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

}
```

Create a CRUD Repo:

```
@EnableScan
public interface TableRepository extends CrudRepository<Table,String> {

    List<Table> findById(String id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those classes are a part of the DynamoDB Java SDK library.

You need to add:
`com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.11.32` (1.11.32 is the current latest version) to your dependencies in your `build.gradle` file.